# What does | mean in this exercise? And how do I solve it?

Tags: inequality

I was doing a practice exam for my SATs and I stumbled across this problem in the inequality section of the Algebra part. And I don't know what that symbol means and how to solve the problem with that symbol there. So can anyone give me a step by step on how to solve this exercise and what does that symbol mean?

{ x | - 2 ≤ x < 3 }

Here's the problem as it appears in my study guide with the solution to the left. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What symbol are you referring to?

Comment: What symbol are you referring to?

Comment: Sense of deja vu...

Comment: To whoever may know, what software can one use to draw diagrams like in the picture?

Comment: @GitGud I'm sure [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) could do it.

Comment: I use ipe on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In set theory,  $\color{red}|$ means "such that".

A common alternative is $\color{red}:$.

In your case, this is the set $\{ x\}$ such that $-2 \leq x <3$, so all you have to do it highlight all (real) values of $x$ satisfying this inequality.

Typically, if the endpoint is included, we color it in black, or leave it white if the endpoint is excluded.

Incidentally, a more-compact way of writing this set is simply $[-2,3)$ where the '$[$' indicates the fact that the left endpoint is *included* and the '$)$' indicates that the right endpoint is excluded.

In general, $\{ x|P(x)\}$ (or $\{x: P(x)\}$) is the set of all $x$ satisfying some property $P(x)$ (which is mentioned either in mathematical symbols or in words).

Comment: I saw a guy use $\ni$ for "such that".... I never really liked it. What's your thought?

Answer (score 0):

each time you have {x | ...} it means "set of all x which are doing ..." and here it is the set of all x superior or equal to -2 and strictly under 3

I guess you need to draw this set on your scale